# Use environment variable to set container version inside Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

It is possible to use an environment variable to set the container version inside the Dockerfile?

e.g.:

> .env

```
NODE_VERSION=12.14.0-alpine
```

> Dockerfile

```
ARG NODE_VERSION

FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}

[...]
```

And if it is possible, is ok to set the container version like that?
I'm using macOS and Docker v19.03.5

Comment: Does the proposed Dockerfile you show work?  I'd expect it to; see [Understand how ARG and FROM interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact) in the Dockerfile documentation.  (It's not an environment variable, though.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Not as I expected. I want to get the NODE_VERSION env variable from .env file. But considering the answers, I think it is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get an access to env variables by using `--build-arg` docker build command argument.

```sh
$ docker build --build-arg NODE_VERSION=12.14.0-alpine
```

More tutorial information is documented here: https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use ENV inside your Dockerfile to setup ENVs. For example

```
#Declare Variables

ENV SERVICE_NAME services/clicks
ENV PKG_PATH /root/home/package
ENV GO_VERSION 1.12.0
ENV ALPINE_VERSION 3.9
FROM golang:GO_VERSION-alpineALPINE_VERSION
```